# Invalid Response in Ajax POST Django

Tags: jquery, django, ajax, post

In trying to post data using Django class-based views (CreateView), I encountered an issue. Ajax is unable to post data.

models.py

```
 class UserProfile(geo_models.Model):
    user = geo_models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=geo_models.CASCADE)
    user_loc = geo_models.PointField(null=False, srid=20137)
    post_date = geo_models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
    USERNAME_FIELD =''

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('rent_app:user-create', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
    def __unicode__(self):
    return self.id
```

views.py

```
class UserProfileCreate(CreateView):
    model = UserProfile
    form_class = UserProfileModelForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
    template_name = 'rent_app/filter_by_distance.html'


<head>
{% load static %}
{% load leaflet_tags %}
{% load geojson_tags %}

{% block extra_assets %}
  {% leaflet_js %}
  {% leaflet_css %}
{% endblock %}
</head>
{% block content %}
<body>
{% leaflet_map "map" callback="ourfunction" %}

</body>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
      var csrftoken = "{{ csrf_token }}";

      function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
        // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
        return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
      }

      $.ajaxSetup({
        beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
          if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
          }
        }
      });

    function ourfunction(map, options) {
      map.locate({setView: true, maxZoom: 16});
map.on('locationfound', onLocationFound);

    function onLocationFound(e) { 
    var radius = e.accuracy;
    var lat = e.latlng.lat;
    var lng = e.latlng.lng;
    var user_loc = "Point ("+lat+" "+lng+")"
    var counter = 0;
    //var user_loc=(e.latlng.lat+e.latlng.lng,srid=20137);
    postdate = new Date(); 
    var datetime = postdate.getDate() + "/"
                + (postdate.getMonth()+1)  + "/" 
                + postdate.getFullYear() + " @ "  
                + postdate.getHours() + ":"  
                + postdate.getMinutes() + ":" 
                + postdate.getSeconds();
    console.log(user_loc);

 $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "/user_create/",
            data: {"id": ++counter,
            "user_loc": user_loc,
            "post_date": postdate,
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'},
            success: function (response) {
              console.log(counter,user_loc,postdate);
                // if not valid user, alert the user
                if(!response["valid"]){
                    alert("Invalid data, Unable to post!");
                }
            },
            error: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
    }
    }  
  </script>
  {% endblock %}
```

Comment: can you send error message, in js and python

Comment: @harshilsuthar In Django POST is 200 (OK), but the javascript code shows the alert above "Invalid data, unable to Post!"

Comment: try to log response in ajax success, it will show if any error occurs or not

Comment: @harshilsuthar How do I do that? It has a code for invalid response, how do I do that for a valid response? I have `error:function(response)` I doesn't put out anything.